# Php form Update database not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, edit

Cant seem to update my SQL through a HTML form using PHP, can someone help

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) { 
  $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE  nmc_cd, nmc_category, nmc_publisher SET " . 
                 "nmc_cd.CDTitle='$_POST[CDTitle]', " .
                 "nmc_cd.CDYear='$_POST[CDYear]', " . 
                 "nmc_cd.CDPrice='$_POST[CDPrice]', " .
                 "nmc_category.catDesc='$_POST[catDesc]', " .
                 "nmc_publisher.pubName='$_POST[pubName]' " .
                 "WHERE CDID='$_POST[CDID]'";
}
```

is my SQL query the problem??

Comment: before you worry about how to fix the update, you should worry about fixing the gaping [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com) before your server gets trashed.

Comment: good programming practices should start early. your dinky school project could become the next google, ugly warts and all.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the sql query from your php page, copying it and running it directly on the database. Does it succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your code, you're never actually performing the query (with `mysql_query($query_string)`). Also, you were missing the closing `}` if your if statement. If all that is fine, then your SQL query looks okay although I would try to run it against the DB (your interpolated string) to make sure the SQL generated is good.

You'll also want to pass your form variables through `mysql_real_escape_string` to make sure that you are avoiding SQL injection attacks (or just malformed SQL in your case). See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: did you mean this

mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);

};

Comment: if you want to be more explicit, then sure. Otherwise the last opened connection will be used. Also, I was just giving an example... I think   the proper methods to use are `mysqli_query` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){ 
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE  nmc_cd, nmc_category, nmc_publisher SET nmc_cd.CDTitle='"; $UpdateQuery .= $_POST[CDTitle]."', nmc_cd.CDYear='".$_POST[CDYear]."', nmc_cd.CDPrice='"; $UpdateQuery .= $_POST[CDPrice]."',nmc_category.catDesc='";
$UpdateQuery .= $_POST[catDesc]."',nmc_publisher.pubName='";
$UpdateQuery .= $_POST[pubName]."' WHERE CDID='".$_POST[CDID]."'"; //run query
}
```

or just transfer all the Post variables to `$something` and use that inside the query